# Errors when I start the Python shell, errors from a script I ran a week ago

Tags: python, linux, file, shell

I've been learning python and I there is a problem with my Python interactive shell on one of my systems. It runs a script on every python-interactive-mode start(without arguments). I don't know where to look for a process that does this, I've programmed a lot of small scripts on this system, and I can see what script is messing around,

When I do this:

```
user@Host ~/Python Scripts> python
```

I get:

```
Python 3.4.2 (default, Feb 21 2015, 22:19:02) 
[GCC 4.9.2 20150212 (Red Hat 4.9.2-6)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
# ! / u s r / b i n / e n v   p y t h o n 
 finished
Failed calling sys.__interactivehook__
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/opt/python-3.4.2/lib/python3.4/site.py", line 396, in register_readline
    import rlcompleter
  File "/usr/local/opt/python-3.4.2/lib/python3.4/rlcompleter.py", line 161, in <module>
    readline.set_completer(Completer().complete)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'set_completer'
>>> quit()
```

Here is the file I ran, and is run on every python start:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

try:
    number = int(input("Enter a number: "))
    print(number)
    aFile = open('modules.py')
    for i in aFile:
        print(aFile.readline(), end=' ')

except ValueError:
    print('Not a number, please re-enter:')
    number = int(input('Enter a number: '))
    print(number)

except IOError:
    print('Cannot open file')

print('finished')
```

What is causing this and how do I fix it?

EDIT #1

The system is Fedora 21, the file modules.py and the script that runs on start of the interactive shell are scripts that have never been edited on a Windows system.

The system has not been rebooted for 11 day's.

Here is:

```
~/Python Scripts> file tryexcept.py
tryexcept.py: Python script, ASCII text executable
```

EDIT #2

I have a readline.py in my current working directory:

```
~/Python Scripts> ls | grep readline
readline.py
```

Comment: Did you edit/write that file on a Windows machine? What does `file <that-script>` say?

Comment: unrelated but you can just `print(i, end=' ')`, you are already iterating over the file object, you should also close the file or just use `with` to open it

Comment: @EtanReisner I'll edit my question, I forgot to inform about the system, I'll add that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The last part of `rlcompleter.py` trys to import readline and then runs the line you error on.

```
try:
    import readline
except ImportError:
    pass
else:
    readline.set_completer(Completer().complete)
    # Release references early at shutdown (the readline module's
    # contents are quasi-immortal, and the completer function holds a
    # reference to globals).
    atexit.register(lambda: readline.set_completer(None))
```

There must be a `readline.py` file somewhere in your path that you are importing instead of the actual python module. If you don't have a readline.py but once had then look for a `readline.pyc` file.

Put a `import readline;print(readline.__file__)` in your interpreter and see what exactly you are importing

Answer (score 5):

I ran into the same problem in a Fedora 21 system. What happens in my case is that I was trying to run the python interpreter within a deleted folder.

This happens because I navigate to a folder, let say **Dropbox** in the command line. I then delete the **Dropbox** folder using *Files* application. Back to console, the current folder was still **Dropbox**.

Running python from this deleted folder causes the same error.